# Product and Unit Testing: same workspace?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, version-control

For a long time we kept unit testing as a separate project/workspace that occasionally we attached to product project to run unit tests on the fly.

Recently we decided that the ability to run unit tests on the fly is really important for our daily work. To implement it in Visual Studio 2010 we put product and unit testing in the same TFS2010 workspace.

The huge drawback is that product and unit testing check-ins are mixed.

Is there any trick or better approach to avoid this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in my project we have used same workspace under TFS for both app code and unit testing but we had separate project for unittesting and haven't mixed them with main project solution.

Again, in TFS they are stored under separate folder in separate branch.

Answer (score 0):

Why would this be a problem? The unit test only makes sense along with the actual production code. Keep it in a seperate project, same workspace and solution file. Unit testing is all about fast feedback and mixed checkins only makes traceability better.

Comment: I see, but when you are reviewing product check-ins you would go through many unit testing ones and I would prefer not.

Comment: Hmfph - my updated answer is pending peer review - Sorry for the deplayed response...